# Is there a way to log events from my Android application to Stackdriver with logback-android?

Tags: android, logging, google-cloud-platform, logback

I am looking for the most convenient way to log entries from my Android application to Stackdriver. My code is in Kotlin using the Flutter framework.

I am already using [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) due to its usage by a library I'm dependent on, so a SLF4J appender to Stackdriver would be most suitable but I couldn't find anything like it. I also tried using the [Google Cloud Logging Library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) but it seems to not support Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of thinking about this issue, and due to the fact that a service account shouldn't be located at the client-side (the Flutter app), I realized the best way is to implement a `\log` endpoint at the server-side and send logs using authenticated requests.